# How do you make apache return a status 200 response code on a post to a url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want apache to return a status code of 200 in response to post requests on a specific path

e.g. /api/mypath/foo

Is this possible with a RewriteRule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following code in htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} POST /api/mypath/foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=200]
```

This will return the 200ok status for /api/mypath/foo if it is accessed using POST method.

Comment: is this specific to a certain version? does not seem to work here http://www.htaccesscheck.com/

Comment: @thedjaney this works almost on all versions. The problem with htaccess check site is that they dont support the_request variable.

Answer (score -3):

I'm using nginx now
This is how its done in nginx

```
location  / {
    return 200 '' ;
    access_log off;
  }
```

Comment: I need to this exact thing but in apache. So far apache seems way more complicated than nginx :D